# java - How to make the list go beside each other (horizontally) instead of going down (vertically).

Tags: java, alignment, horizontallist

how do I make the list go beside each other (horizontally) instead of going down (vertically).

Example:

January (this is what I keep getting)
S M T W T F S
1

2

3

4

5

...

January (this is what I wanted to get)
S M T W T F S
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
8 9 ...

Thanks any help would be appreciated, I'm new at this and I can't figure it out. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
System.out.print("Value");
```

instead of :

```
System.out.println("Value");
```

And don't forget to add a

```
System.out.println("");
```

at the end to flush the buffer.

Comment: You also need a newline to flush the buffer to it actually prints.

Comment: So many people don't seem to know about the no-params `System.out.println()` method...

Comment: @bcsb1001 What use is there to the no-params method ? Printing a blank line ?

Comment: @Simon Yes, i.e. exactly the same as `System.out.println("")` as you did, but shorter and clearer.

Comment: @bcsb1001 Shorter indeed, but clearer I would argue. Thanks for the info still.